# Short story as a letter to original colonisers of earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-colonization

I am trying to track the title of a short story which is written as a message from an alien race to the original colonisers of earth apologising for the collapse of the experiment and advising the colonisers they will be rescued soon. It turns out the message is meant for a particular race of people. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I quickly found this short story by Googling `Arthur C. Clark If any of you are white we can cure you` Fortunately, I remembered the author and the last punchline of the story.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's "[Reunion](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62001)", by Arthur C. Clarke.

It's a message from the descendants of the original colonisers of planet Earth.

> People of Earth, do not be afraid. We come in peace — and why not? For we are your cousins; we have been here before.

They describe how the colonists became ill with a disfiguring disease, that caused strife between the victims of the disease and those that were immune to it.

The twist is in the ending of the message:

> If any of you are still white, we can cure you.